# Unable to install nvidia drivers because aws gcp images appear on /boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (an upgrade from 20.04 LTS).

Today, after `snap refresh`, my additional display stopped working due to nvidia driver issues (system defaulted to non-nvidia driver).

Unforntunately I cannot select any nvidia driver from `Software & Updates` because some weird kernels like `initrd.img-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency` or `initrd.img-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency` start to occupy my `/boot` partition. There is no space left on this partition and selecting a driver fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Unfortunately my /boot partition was not big enough to fit all that kernels. But thanks anyway since cleaning up the /boot was part of the solution.